# How can I get the Sharp OSA SDK for .NET

Tags: .net, printers

According to one of the comments on http://sentryfile.blogspot.com/2006/11/copier-apis-myth.html, there is a .NET SDK for interfacing with Sharp printers (called the OSA SDK?). I'm wanting this as I want to write a little system tray application that pops up a message whenever something like a fax comes through, or whatever. Unfortunately, the SDK seems to be impossible to get ahold of. I called Sharp, and they seemed to have no idea of what I was talking about, and told me to contact our dealer.

Shouldn't Sharp have this? Has anyone else had any luck getting ahold of this elusive SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is...Took awhile to find it:

http://www.sterlingofficesystems.com/Developer%20Program.htm

For some reason, it's not listed on the Sharp main website, yet the OSA SDK is listed as a feature of several Sharp printer products.  The left hand doesn't know what the right hand is doing.  That's not uncommon for such large companies.

Answer (score 0):

The OSA SDK is only available to members of the [Sharp Development partner program](http://www.sharp-partners.com/PartnerPrograms/DeveloperProgram/tabid/409/Default.aspx). You have to pay and be approved for membership.